# Spring Boot: Project won't compile after changing gradle dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a rather strange issue with my Spring boot application which has been driving me around the bend.

So I have my Spring boot API which is in Github and uses Gradle to manage my dependencies. If I add a dependency and compile the project everything works fine. However, if I decide I do not need said dependency anymore and remove it from my build file, my Project will no longer compile stating it cant find packages / symbols for dependencies **unrelated** to what I removed.

Has anyone seen something like this before? As an FYI I'm using Intellij.

To give an example, here is my current build file:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.2"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.21.0"
    id "idea"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
}

ext {
    avroVersion = "1.10.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
    }
}

avro {
    createSetters = true
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
}

apply plugin: "war"

dependencies {
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '6.6'
    compile group: 'co.elastic.logging', name: 'logback-ecs-encoder', version: '0.5.2'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.860'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache', version: '2.4.3'

//    compile 'redis.clients:jedis:3.5.1'

    implementation group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.6.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server', version: '2.4.2'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'


    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.11.2'

    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
    compile group: 'org.passay', name: 'passay', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt
    compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.12.0'


    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-schema-registry-client', version: '6.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: '6.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'monitoring-interceptors', version: '6.0.0'
    compile(group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-streams-avro-serde', version: '6.0.0') {
        exclude(module: 'log4j-over-slf4j')
    }

    compile "org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.1"
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:${avroVersion}"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.test.TestApplication'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Now let's assume I don't want logstash so I remove it, this happens with any dependency

```
    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '6.6'
```

Now my build file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.2"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "com.commercehub.gradle.plugin.avro" version "0.21.0"
    id "idea"
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_14
}

ext {
    avroVersion = "1.10.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
    }
}

avro {
    createSetters = true
    fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
}

apply plugin: "war"

dependencies {
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'

// REMOVED    implementation group: 'net.logstash.logback', name: 'logstash-logback-encoder', version: '6.6'
    compile group: 'co.elastic.logging', name: 'logback-ecs-encoder', version: '0.5.2'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.11.860'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-cache', version: '2.4.3'

//    compile 'redis.clients:jedis:3.5.1'

    implementation group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'

    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-elasticsearch', version: '4.0.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-client', version: '5.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: '2.4.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.6.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server', version: '2.4.2'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.21'


    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.11.2'

    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'org.openapitools', name: 'jackson-databind-nullable', version: '0.2.1'

    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
    compile group: 'org.passay', name: 'passay', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '30.0-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt
    compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.12.0'


    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-schema-registry-client', version: '6.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-avro-serializer', version: '6.0.0'
    compile group: 'io.confluent', name: 'monitoring-interceptors', version: '6.0.0'
    compile(group: 'io.confluent', name: 'kafka-streams-avro-serde', version: '6.0.0') {
        exclude(module: 'log4j-over-slf4j')
    }

    compile "org.apache.avro:avro:1.10.1"
    implementation "org.apache.avro:avro:${avroVersion}"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.test.TestApplication'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Once I hit build I'll get non related logstash compilation errors such as in various classes:

```
java: package lombok does not exist
java: package org.openapitools.jackson.nullable does not exist
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Getter
java: package org.springframework.data.domain does not exist
java: package org.openapitools.jackson.nullable does not exist
```

I've tried reimporting my project, I've deleted it and pull down a fresh copy from Git..I'm at a  loss now. Please if anyone has come across this let me know as google is failing me now :-/

Many thanks

EDIT: Please note for clarification, this seems to only happen when I have Intellij performing the build and Run.

[image]

If I switch the below to Gradle I've no issues remove dependencies as described above. However, I'd like to keep Intellij performing the build and run.

Edit:
Adding gradle-wrapper.properties in case it helps

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-bin.zip

zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Also, following a suggestion below, I purged the cache in Intellij which Did solve the problem, However, once I remove another dependency I'm back to getting the errors above.

**Second Edit**

I'm not sure it matters but I noticed since Lombok is the main error I checked the annotation settings.

Why is there a default & a gradle imported, Would that be causing any of the issues?

[image]

Comment: In IntelliJ Idea you have an option to Invalidate Caches/ Restart. So File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: Thanks for the response! That does work. However if I remove another dependancy I have to invalidate the cache again!! Surely that can't be correct?

Comment: There were a similar question, regarding caches, already asked on intellij support page, maybe some of the answers could help you too.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000667144-Why-do-I-have-to-invalidate-my-cache-fairly-often-

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah I went through the page and the links. Still no joy. I've added an edit to my question if that helps

Comment: And answer for your edit, that's normal procedure, Default is the whole project, Gradle imported are parts of your project, so in your case it's a main and test part. But this is not a reason why you need to invalidate caches after every dependency removal.

Comment: Ok so this is strange. I upgraded Intellij just there (I was one version behind) and everything is now working.

Comment: Did you run "Reload" from Gradle Tool window after removing dependency?

Comment: Yup, I most certainly did. I cant for the live of me figure out why this was happening. And it was happening to 3 other projects that I have

Comment: Why are you overriding all the dependencies versions yourself? Spring Boot's Dependency Management configures almost all of those dependencies with the compatible versions .

Comment: mmm, I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean I should remove where i specify a specific version?